# Python Selenium Webdriver won't run, even when PATHed properly, and script written as instructed

Tags: java, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to learn Webdriver for Python, using a basic understanding of Python, and a more extensive understanding of Selenium and JAVA. I'm following the guide found [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html). My code:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
assert "Google" in driver.title
sb = driver.find_element_by_name(lst-ib)
sb.clear()
sb.send_keys("Youtube")
sb.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

Now, running this in PyCharm will return:

```
C:\Users\mbrenn002c\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe C:/Users/mbrenn002c/PycharmProjects/PyDriver/Webdriver.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mbrenn002c/PycharmProjects/PyDriver/Webdriver.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Users\mbrenn002c\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 145, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "C:\Users\mbrenn002c\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\mbrenn002c\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\mbrenn002c\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\mbrenn002c\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line


Process finished with exit code 1
```

My pip packages are: selenium; beautifulsoup4.

My PATH looks as such:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Mirosoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Programs\Python;C:\Pythone34;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\File transfer\Eclipse Items\geckodrver.exe
```

My main question is; What am I doing wrong? As far as I know, I've followed everything correctly and this code should open geckodriver and work as listed. It won't even run with selenium standalone server for webdriver running.

I've tried running it with the same pip and code on my QPython client for my android phone, which returned some call-backs in the console, with this in the end:

```
 Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'log_file'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <seleniumwebdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0xf5e709f0>> ignored
```

It may be worth noting that my phone is not Rooted, and all i've really done is save this one script, and pip install Selenium and beautifulsoup4.

Comment: I did not post the full return log from my phone due to its length and possible lack of relevance to the question. I can post it if needed, or elaborate/expand on any pieces of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Expected
>   browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default
>   location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no
>   binary flag set on the command line

Exception is clearly states that Firefox has installed different directory than Selenium. Trying to access the default path but couldn't find. You need to describe where exactly firefox has installed in your code.

Use the snippet below;

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('path/to/installed firefox binary')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

driver.get("http://www.google.com")
assert "Google" in driver.title
sb = driver.find_element_by_name(lst-ib)
sb.clear()
sb.send_keys("Youtube")
sb.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

Comment: Ran the code and supplemented the correct directory for geckodriver. it output the following:     C:\Users\mbrenn002c\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe C:/Users/mbrenn002c/PycharmProjects/PyDriver/Webdriver.py
  File "C:/Users/mbrenn002c/PycharmProjects/PyDriver/Webdriver.py", line 6
    binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\Users\mbrenn002c\Desktop\File transfer\C drive drops\eclipse')
                          ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: 'C:\Users\mbrenn002c\Desktop\File transfer\C drive drops\eclipse' spaces "C drive drops" are reason of syntax issue. Please correct as like "C_drive_drops"

Comment: I've corrected all combinations of spaces and '_'s in my code, it still throws the same error.

Comment: This is obviously a syntax error, if your original issue resolved please ask this with another question